# Outlook Calendar Sync Issues. Exchange Account.

Tags: exchange, lg-g2, outlook.com

Someone asked a similar question, and I tried the answers, but they didn't work.

My problem is at some point my Android Calendar entries for my Outlook.com / Exchange account disappeared.  I have an LG G2 and have setup my Outlook.com account as an MS Exchange account, preferring that over the Outlook.com app.  I have uninstalled and re-installed the account several times.  Each time the mail and contacts show up again fine.  But the calendar contacts don't show up.  I see the account within the calendar app, and have selected the account to show, but nothing shows up.  I have also tried deleting the data for email, calendar, and contact apps, thinking that there is data cached that the Calendar app thinks it's already seen.  But this does not seem to help.

Comment: Could you link the similar question?  Ideally we would update it to contain any additional solutions.