# Outlook.com ActiveSync no longer working, even after recreation

Tags: active-sync, outlook.com

My Outlook.com ActiveSync for contacts and calendar simply stopped working a few days ago. The locally added contacts and calendar entries are there, but nothing is synced with MS.

In the hope of fixing the issue, I deleted the activesync account (beware: now lost all contacts and calendar entries on device!!) and recreated it.

The account is correctly set up, and the email part (that I don't use) seems to work, but *no* contacts or calendar entries are synced down from `outlook.com` / `live.com`.

Several delete+add and phone reboots didn't help.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/140078/6480

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/88061/6480

Answer (score 0):

After messing around, I finally noticed that, after creating the fresh ActiveSync account on my android phone, the eas account's EMail showed a kind of "welcome mail" from MS, that read in the subject "ACTION REQUIRED ..." (paraphrased).

I took a closer look at this Email, and it asked me to set up the Outlook App. And if I didn't wish to set up the Outlook App, I **should follow a link to continue syncing with the built-in apps**. I didn't notice this the first few times, because normally I don't use outlook.com mail and normally I just ignore Welcome Mails.

After I clicked this MS link, the sync started to work again for both contacts and calendar.

<sub>Let's just not start a rant on how MS wasted dunno how many hours of my time through this ... *sigh*</sub>